# Titanium: How to get the objects or native object created from .js

Tags: javascript, templates, titanium

I am doing dynamic layout in IOS developing: For example there are many tableviewCell templates described in js file,  so I want to get the templateCell v from js.

For example, I have a TemplateView.js, as following:

```
var contentView = Titanium.UI.creatView({
        backgroundImage:'../images/background.png',
        height:320,
        width:44
});

var button = Titanium.UI.createButton({
        backgroundImage:'../images/send.png',
        height:33,
        width:33
});

contentView.add(button);
```

Now how can I get the objects or the root object(contentView) created from eval TemplateView.js?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

var row = Alloy.createController('TemplateView', payload).getView();

$.TableName.appendRow(row);

Comment: Thanks,   I am now using  .js only,  is there any method without Alloy?